# C# close dropdown on enter

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

How can I close a dropdown list, when <kbd>Enter</kbd> (key 13) is pressed?

```
private void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b')
            e.Handled = true;
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            //close open dropdown list
}
```

Comment: This happens by default when you press enter, you won't need any code for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close up any Combobox try

```
  DroppedDown = false;
```

In your code sample it could be

```
private void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b')
            e.Handled = true;
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            (sender as ComboBox).DroppedDown = false;// <- close opened dropdown list
}
```

Mayhaps a better way is to preserve default behavior and let .net do its work:

```
private void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyChar < ' ') // <- preserve default behavior for Enter, Esc etc.
      return;

    // Special conditions here
    if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b')
      e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: For any other key on the keyboard I would agree, but this happens by default with the enter key!

Comment: Yes, you are quite right (it's default behavior), but in the code sample that is in the original question, the message (KeyPress) is handled (e.Handled = true), that's why default doesn't work.

Comment: Alright, this does close my dropdown menu, but it reopens it immediately somewhy